# Which statistical model to apply for same participant exposed with different treatments

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

Briefly I have n number of participants and each one of these participants i am exposing to different treatments at the same time.

For example
First step: I have 3 different materials (plastic, plastic used in prosthetic and human skin) and each of the participant is allowed to touch each of these materials for n seconds.

Second Step: I will design a questionnaire to measure which of the material is more desirable to touch!!. I am considering of blind folding the participant.

Third Step: Use a statistical method to validate my hypothesis (i.e., prosthetic arm is better to touch)

So accomplish a scenario like above. Which statistical model will be advisable to use and what are key points i should consider.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would question whether or not time is really an interesting factor to evaluate in your study. For what reason do you think it would be an interesting aspect to evaluate?

Secondly, as you have partially noted, our experience of touch is affected by our other senses. Blindfolding removes vision, but you could also consider earphones with white noise, removing sound. Testing whether including or removing each of these senses affects questionnaire responses is a possibility.

Thirdly, with regards to your statistical analysis, what sort of measures will the participants report? Will they rank preferences or rate against various scales? The nature of the data here will have a big impact on what analysis you can perform.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! It has given great insights to work on. +1